# Cannot identify elements during runtime using Appium

Tags: android, selenium, mobile, appium

I am new to appium and Java, so please bear with me.

I am trying to automate an app on an emulator. I am able to inspect the elements under UIAUTOMATORVIEWER, however when i run the code, no element in the page can be identified. The app does open up, but elements cannot be identified.

This is the property of the inspected element:
Class: android.widget.Button
Content-desc: LOGIN

This is part of the page source during runtime, as you can see the login button is present in the page:

This is the gist of my code:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());         
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Google Pixel 2");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "8.0");
cap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");    
cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.kruxanalytics.kruxmetrix");
cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.kruxanalytics.kruxmetrix.MainActivity");

I have tried the following find element methods:

driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("LOGIN").click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@content-desc='LOGIN']")).click();

Appium log mostly contains this:
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"sessionId":"5f7bca9b-2e8b-46a7-9727-53a85e0d6df0","status":7,"value":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError
```

Comment: Do you use any wait mechanism just before your find statements?

Comment: Yeah, i did add that as well. it just waits and waits, but elements don't get identified. Could it be the design of the app? cos i can work on the default calculator app on the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I think the application is hybrid so you need to include chromedriverExecutable capability , by identifying the location of the driver that suits the device in the emulator, I also have a problem in running Appium on android 8 so try to target another version and it will work.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example adding a code snippet might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your application is capable of loading immediately, most probably you need to introduce a [WebDriverWait](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) in order to query the application for the specified element for a specific time span.

So change this line:

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("LOGIN").click();
```

to this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,30)
        .until(ExpectedConditions
                .elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@content-desc='LOGIN ']")))
        .click();
```

More information: [Explicit wait - Mobile Test Automation with Appium](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781787280168/6/ch06lvl1sec31/explicit-wait)

Comment: Hey Dmitri,
i tried this as well. The code just keeps on waiting forever and the elements are not being identified. I am able to work on the default calculator in the emulator, so i am assuming its a app-specific problem and not that my capabilities are set wrong. So do i need to contact the developer? and what kind of questions do i need to ask him?

Comment: @Dmitri T Better to ask him first, like I did, if he's using any wait mechanism before speculating about a possible cause of his problem.

Comment: @Dmitri the app is developed in Ionic, i dont know if that makes any difference